# Get drawable size without scale

Tags: android, width, drawable

I want to get the size of my drawable without scaling.
My function take a Drawable and can't take a an URI :

```
 static private Drawable applyTheme (Drawable drawable)
{
    Bitmap bitmap;
    if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) 
    {
        Bitmap notMutable =((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();
        bitmap = notMutable.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

        Log.w(TAG, "bitmap width:"+bitmap.getWidth());
    }

    // etc...
}
```

Actually this code print 93px as width for my drawable whereas the original image width is 140px.
The difficulty is that I can't get the Drawable with URI because my function must not take this in argument.

Just need to have the original width & height of my Drawable.

And ration imageScale/appScale return always 1...

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using `Drawable.getIntrinsicWidth` & `Drawable.getIntrinsicHeight`?

Comment: whats your device dpi and whats the folder you keep your BitmapDrawable in

Comment: getAppContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi command give me 160, so mdpi. My resources are in hdpi, and must not be in others dpi folders... I thinks density ratio could be the best solution but I'm not able to get the original bitmap dpi folder...

Comment: so its all correct: 93/140 == 160/240 == mdpi/hdpi == 0.666

Comment: I'ts a bad approche, I can't use a static value ;) I must get it from function. Because MY phone is mdpi but there is a lot of other phone with others dpis